# Too many redirects when checking $_Session variables

Tags: php, session

I have this script at the top of my pages that check valid users or not:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])) {
    if ($_SESSION["loggedin"] == true) {
        $res = checkKey($_SESSION["uiid"]);
        if ($res > 0) {
            header("Location: admin.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            header("Location: scripts.php?action=logout");
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

But when I try to access the page, I get a page in Chrome saying too many redirects. I've seen other answers on SO that resolve this type of thing by using `isset()`, but I'm already doing that at the top before it cycles down through the rest. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if this is on index.php it will obvious cause and infinite loop for those not logged in

Comment: If this is your code in `admin.php` then you need to remove/change the `header("Location: admin.php"); exit;`. If this is your code in `index.php`, you need to remove/change all the instances of `header("Location: index.php"); exit;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if the user is NOT logged in and this code is on index.php, you will endlessly loop on going to index.php.

The error shown on chrome means this, there's an infinite cycle of redirects.

As per your comment this is on Admin.php, note that this will execute everytime you "redirect" the page. so if you just skip the redirecting when it's "Right", then your issue will be solved

```
if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])) {
    if ($_SESSION["loggedin"] == true) {
        $res = checkKey($_SESSION["uiid"]);
        if ($res > 0) {
            // Here we assume user is an admin, so there's no need to redirect him
            // he's at the right place
        } else {
            header("Location: scripts.php?action=logout");
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Note that this would still happen if the user is logged in and `checkKey($_SESSION["uiid"]) > 0;`

Comment: I'm going to give you the answer because you helped me the most and I'm also going to post the code that ultimately got me the desired result

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this hope this will work

```
 if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] == true) {
      $res = checkKey($_SESSION["uiid"]);
 } else {
      header("Location: index.php");
      exit;
 }


 if (!empty($res) && $res > 0) {
      header("Location: admin.php");
      exit;
 } else {
      header("Location: scripts.php?action=logout");
      exit;
 }
```

Comment: Dang. I still get the "too many redirects" error in Chrome. I see why it is happening though, because every time admin.php is navigated to, it has to go through the if statement endless cycle of loops.

Comment: ok please update your code by this   

  if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] == true) {
            $res = checkKey($_SESSION["uiid"]);
            $url = (!empty($res) && $res > 0) ? "admin.php" : "scripts.php?action=logout";
            header("Location: $url");
            exit;
        } else {
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that got the desired result:

```
 if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] == true) {
      $res = checkKey($_SESSION["uiid"]);
 } else {
      header("Location: index.php");
      exit;
 }


 if (empty($res) || $res < 0) {
      header("Location: scripts.php?action=logout");
      exit;
 }
```